# Devart always update the same entity

Tags: oracle, devart

I have a problem with devart when it executes the context.SaveChanges() methods.
For example if there is a problem during the update process (the length of the string is too long for the db field, i have an exception) and for each entity to be saved, devart always taking the entity which produce the error. 
For example i have 3 entity in state modified, if the first produce an exception, the tool will not try to update the two others : it try to update to times more the first one...

Anyone knows how to flag the entity which produce an exception, to ensure, that it will not in the changed list ?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem solved? If not, [please specify](http://www.devart.com/company/contact.html):

1) the name of your template (e.g.: DbContext template)

2) the build number (x.xx.xxx) of dotConnect for Oracle

3) the version of Entity Framework used in your project